# errors while compiling the MuPDF for android platform

Tags: android, mupdf

I want to develop and android application which will help annotate the PDF files in android. Thus, I am using MuPDF to read and Parse the PDF files in android. I am trying to build it as specified in http://www.mupdf.com/doc/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android , but I have encountered the following error:

```
C:/Android-NDK/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libmupdfcore.a(image.o): in function fz_decomp_image_from_stream:jni/../../../source/fitz/image.c:182: error: undefined reference to 'fz_unpack_tile'
C:/Android-NDK/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libmupdfcore.a(image.o): in function fz_decomp_image_from_stream:jni/../../../source/fitz/image.c:193: error: undefined reference to 'fz_decode_indexed_tile'
C:/Android-NDK/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libmupdfcore.a(image.o): in function fz_decomp_image_from_stream:jni/../../../source/fitz/image.c:200: error: undefined reference to 'fz_decode_tile'
C:/Android-NDK/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libmupdfcore.a(load-tiff.o): in function fz_load_tiff:jni/../../../source/fitz/load-tiff.c:804: error: undefined reference to 'fz_unpack_tile'
C:/Android-NDK/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libmupdfcore.a(load-png.o): in function fz_load_png:jni/../../../source/fitz/load-png.c:567: error: undefined reference to 'fz_unpack_tile'
```

On analyzing the first error, I understood that fz_unpack_tile, fz_decode_tile, fz_decode_indexed_tile are defined in fitz/draw-unpack.c

Now, I am not sure of how to continue from here

Answer (score 1):

You asked this on irc yesterday, and I suggested that you do a complete clean, then rebuild from scratch capturing the logs and post them somewhere.

The code as supplied in git builds just fine in android for us. Without more information, no one is going to be able to help you.